# Changing video depending on the screen resolution

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm having this problem, you may be able to give me a solution

I have two videos: 1920x1080 and 1280x720 right?

trying to change the video depending on the screen resolution i found out that the solution is using media tags

```html
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
            <source src="{{asset('static/videos/video-fisica-1920x1080.mp4')}}" media="screen and (min-width: 1919px)">
            <source src="{{asset('static/videos/video-fisica.mp4')}}" media="screen and (max-width: 1919px)">
        </video>
```

The thing is that I'm testing this on a Macbook pro retina 13' and It's always rendering the 1920x1080 video and I'm brokeing the pages layout
If I change the order like this

```
            <source src="{{asset('static/videos/video-fisica.mp4')}}" media="screen and (max-width: 1919px)">
            <source src="{{asset('static/videos/video-fisica-1920x1080.mp4')}}" media="screen and (min-width: 1919px)">
```

The video-fisica.mp4 will be rendered

And also, with this setup on my localhost works perfect but when I uploaded to my server it's not.

```css
video { width: 100%; }
video source { width: 100%; height: auto; }

@media (max-width:767px){.elementor-hidden-phone{display:none}}
@media (min-width:767px){.elementor-phone{display:none}}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    header {
        background-image: url("/static/imagenes/header.jpg"); // This is actually working.
    }
}
```

Adding more to this,

Thank you

Comment: Can you create a working example what you have tried so far please

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier way using CSS, media query without extra script.

You can make two div class, one for Video big and one for Video Small

```html
<div class="video_pc" src="video_big.mp4" > 

<div class="video_mobile" src="video_small.mp4">
```

and then you can hide one or another as the screen size differs.

```css
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 1919px) {
    .video_pc {
        display: none;
    }
}
    
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    .video_mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
    
</style>
```

So if the screen size goes less than 1919px, video_pc class will be hidden
if the size goes bigger than 1920px, video_mobile class will be hidden likewise.

Comment: This will load both videos everytime, just on of them will not be displayed, there is no reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Safari has removed support for media queries to determine which video source to load. https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#attr-source-media

As for the second code snippet: When you say it doesn't work perfectly, is it possible that the css is correct but the image isn't loading? Check the path to make sure it's correct. Depending on what kind of server you're running the routing may not be the same as on your localhost as well.

Comment: Im always using Chrome. and the image is loading correctly. I'm just having problems with the video